# How to use Sharepoint Server Search (KeywordQuery class) to search through a sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

We have a requirement where users are to be allowed to search a list called "Reports" from the front-end, and advanced search, such as `author:"John Smith"` or `filetype:docx`, is to be supported.

We decided that this can be achieved using [Sharepoint Server Search API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn423226%28v=office.15%29.aspx#bk%5fQuerySOM) (using the [Keyword Query Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558911.aspx)). Also, since it is possible that all users don't have access to all items in the list, we decided to go with the approach to use a web method with elevated privileges to query the list.

This is my attempt so far...

```
public string GetSearchResults(string listname, string searchQuery)
{
    SPUser superUser = SPContext.Current.Web.AllUsers[@"SHAREPOINT\SYSTEM"];
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url, superUser.UserToken))
    {
        KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(site);
        keywordQuery.QueryText = searchQuery;

        //where should listname be specified?

        SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(); 
        ResultTableCollection resultTableCollection = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery); 
        var resultTables = resultTableCollection.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults); 
        ResultTable resultTable = resultTables.FirstOrDefault(); 
        DataTable dataTable = resultTable.Table; 
    }

    //how to parse result to filter only items in given list?
}
```

...but what I don't understand is how to restrict search to only a given list or how to parse the search result to retrieve items of the list matching the search query.

I'm new to Sharepoint search, so any pointers would help.

Comment: There should be "Path" property in your results table which contains url of result item. You can try to use it to filter the results. Something like 'Path:"\*Reports\*"' might do the trick. But of course it mainly depends on you search configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible either to give list path or list guid in query text

```
keywordQuery.QueryText = "Path:/Sales/Lists/Prospects/ (contentclass:STS_ListItem OR IsDocument:True) -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople ";
```